# Como usar as duas versões do anaconda no linux?

Tags: python, linux, anaconda

Boa tarde pessoal, estou estudando python para projetos e fui recomendado a usar o pacote anaconda. Sou usuário linux(ubuntu) e por conseguinte fiz a instalação dos dois pacotes no meu sistema. Atualmente no projeto da faculdade, estamos trabalhando com analise de dados, contudo não consigo fazer uso do pacote anaconda 2(com a versão 2.7). Só a versão 3 está com path inscrito no script "bash.rc". Eu gostaria de usar as duas versões, pois estamos lidando com as duas versões do projeto e não gostaria de usar "maquinas virtuais, ou mv_env" para instalação da versão 2.7. Logo pergunto existe alguma maneira?
Fico no aguardo pessoal.

PS: Não permitir que o pacote anaconda 2 exportasse o path no script da bash, por prioritariamente usarmos a versão do python 3.X.

Answer (score 1):

Na realidade vc não precisa usar duas versões do anaconda (e não esta relacionado ao bashrc, bashrc apenas indica o local da instalação), instale somente uma versão e vc pode ter quantos ambientes precisar, por exemplo, baixe [uma dessas versões](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) e instale. Veja que a diferença é que uma vem com o python 2.7 e a outra com o python 3.6 como default (root). Eu sempre instalo a 3.6.

Se vc instalou a que vem com o pyathon 3.6 e executar o comando para ver a versão (do python), obterá:

```
python --version
Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)
```

Digamos que vc tenha baixado a 3.6 e precise instalar o python 2.7 para um projeto especifico, então faça:

```
conda create -n py27 python=2.7
```

Com isso criamos uma env chamada py27. Para ativa-la faça:

```
$ source activate py27
(py27) sidon@sidon....
```

Perceba que apos a ativação do novo ambiente o seu prompt de comando mudou, acrescentando o nome da env entre parenteses no inicio "(py27)".

Veja agora (depois do ambiente ativo) o que o comando para mostrar a versão obtem:

```
python --version
Python 2.7.13 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
```

Uma vez ativo, qq coisa q vc instale (com o pip, por exemplo), será instalado nesse ambiente.

Vamos supor que apareça um projeto em que seja mandatório trabalhar com o python 3.4, entao basta fazer:

```
conda create -n py34 python=3.4
```

E assim vc tem uma nova env. Para listar todas as suas envs, faça:

```
$ conda-env list
# conda environments:
#
autopart                 /home/sidon/anaconda3/envs/autopart
eztables                 /home/sidon/anaconda3/envs/eztables
gestauto                 /home/sidon/anaconda3/envs/gestauto
llabs                    /home/sidon/anaconda3/envs/llabs
material                 /home/sidon/anaconda3/envs/material
olist                    /home/sidon/anaconda3/envs/olist
py27                  *  /home/sidon/anaconda3/envs/py27
scrum                    /home/sidon/anaconda3/envs/scrum
root                     /home
```

O astecrisco indica qual env está ativa. Para desativar a env atual e voltar para o root, faça:

```
source deactivate
```