# Compilar o código py para exe

Tags: python, python-3.x

Preciso compilar o script em python para torná-lo .exe, porém só consigo com o kernel puro do Python, que não tem a maioria das bibliotecas que usei para desenvolver. O kernel que eu uso para desenvolvimento, é o Anaconda - *ou Conda*. Como faço para compilar o código utilizando o kernel Anaconda ao invés do kernel puro do Python?

**Edit:**
O problema é o kernel que o cx_freeze está utilizando para compilar (atualmente usa o python puro), preciso que seja o kernel do Anaconda, pois preciso de bibliotecas como SciPy, MySQL Connector, etc...

Comment: Opa! Certo, conheço essa questão, porém o meu problema é outro. Não é a compilação em si, mas o kernel que ele usa para compilar

Comment: Python não é compilado para EXE, ele é embudito dentro do exe, mas as libs continuam como pyd (acho que era essa a extensão) e se tiver dependencias que forem .dlls e outros .exe terá que copiar manualmente para a pasta do teu exe gerado a partir da pasta `Lib\site-packages\{pacote}`, copie somente o conteudo.

Comment: Entendi. Na verdade eles ficam com a extenção .pyc. Eu consegui fazer essa 'conversão', só que com o kernel python normal, que não tem a biblioteca SciPy por exemplo, aí quando vou rodar o arquivo EXE (que foi gerado com o cx_freeze), aparece um TraceBack (da biblioteca SciPy), e a aplicação logo fecha. Acredito que se eu 'converter' com o kernel do Conda, a aplicação funcionará corretamente, só que não sei como alternar para este kernel.

Comment: Como eu disse Matheus, tem que copiar os pacotes da pasta lib\site-packages necessários, fora que depende da versão do python que usou, o problema do Python é que sempre tem alguma falta de retrocompatibilidade para estes cx_freeze e pyinstaller, tanto que meio que desisti de tentar compilar para `.exe` uma aplicação grande que tenho e mudei pra C++, claro que isto não é solução, só estou comentando a dificuldade que tive.

Comment: Tem um equivoco na sua pergunta, anconda não é um "kernel", anaconda é uma distribuição python, e conda é um gerenciador de pacotes/envs. Vc pode, sim empacotar toda a distro anaconda em um exe.

Comment: Outro equivoco é achar que os pacotes da distribuição anaconda são exclusividade dela, muito pelo contrário, vc pode istalar o 'SciPy, MySQL Connector, etc...' no que vc chama "kernel puro do python", vc pode instalar tudo que tem no anaconda sem a utilização dela.

Comment: Saiba mais sobre virtualenv no anaconda [nessa resposta,](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/224322/d%C3%BAvidas-sobre-virtualenv/224350#224350) [e nessa.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/223514/como-usar-as-duas-vers%C3%B5es-do-anaconda-no-linux/223520#223520)