# Dúvidas sobre virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

Estou iniciando o desenvolvimento com virtualenv e surgiram algumas dúvidas, são elas:

1. Os scripts Python precisam estar dentro da pasta do ambiente virtual?
2. Na IDE PyCharm, é necessário configurar algo para desenvolver no ambiente virtual ativado?
3. Caso eu precise rodar os scripts em outra máquina que não tenha o ambiente virtual configurado, preciso configurá-lo do zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A resposta para a primeira pergunta é: Não! e parece não fazer sentido, o que eu vejo (e não uso) é o contrario, a venv estar em um diretório em dentro do seu projeto.

Sim, No pycharm vc precisa dizer com qual venv o seu projeto vai trabalhar, cofigure em File/settings/project interpreter.

[image: Configurando o pycharm]

A resposta para a terceira pergunta é: Não necessariamente! O conceito de virtual env á para o desenvolvedor, para que ele possa ter varios ambientes de desenvolvimento em sua estação de trabalho, dessa forma pode-se desenvover projetos em python 2, python 3, etc, bastando para isso "comutar" os ambientes.

Na maquina que vai rodar o projeto precisa ter todos os pacotes requeridos pelo mesmo, estando ou nao em uma virtual env. Para isso use um arquivo de requerimentos, comumente chamado requirements.txt

Para iniciar no gerenciamento de ambientes virtuais em python, considere a utilização do anaconda. Veja, aqui no STOpt, [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/223514/como-usar-as-duas-vers%C3%B5es-do-anaconda-no-linux/223520#223520), e abra essa porta com chave de ouro. :-)