# Como saber quais as bibliotecas estão sendo usadas em um projeto python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, biblioteca

Eu fiz uma instalação de uma aplicação feita em Python, ela funciona basicamente da seguinte forma, ela instala o Python, o programa e no final a instalação copia a pasta com as bibliotecas para a instalação do Python.

Tudo funciona perfeitamente, mas a instalação ficou muito grande por causa das bibliotecas, como tenho muitas bibliotecas que utilizo em outros projetos, e que não tem nada a ver com esta instalação, ficou muito grande, eu tentei escolher o que uso e o que não uso olhando os imports no projeto, mas vire e mexe durante os testes acontecem alguns erros por causa de uma biblioteca que esta faltando, e nem sempre o nome é sugestivo para procurar, no fim das contas tive que deixar todas as bibliotecas com medo de dar algum erro em produção.

Eu consigo de alguma forma saber quais bibliotecas estão sendo usadas em um determinado projeto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De forma rápida e descuidada voce pode "corrigir", fazendo assim:
No ambiente de seu projeto faça:

```
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

No ambiente de produção, faça:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Porque apesar de rápida e fácil, essa forma pode ser considerada "descuidada"? porque dessa maneira vc estara instalando em produção todos os pacotes instalados no ambiente de desenvolvimento, isso, na maioria das vezes, desnecessário.

Mas se vc quer fazer a coisa da forma correta, continue lendo.

Uma boa pratica é sempre iniciar cada projeto em um ambiente virtual único, para isso o ideal é usar um gerenciador de venvs, o que mais gosto é o anacoda/conda que, alem de ser um gerenciador de venv's é, também, um gerenciador de pacotes do python, uma espécie de "distribuição".

Se vc tivesse utilizado essa prática, então no início do desenvolvimento do projeto vc criaria uma env somente com a versão do python que vc utilizaria no projeto e, a medida que fosse precisando das libs iria alimentando um arquivos chamado requeriments.txt, então quando fosse para o ambiente de producção, bastaria fazer:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

### Pipreqs:

Se vc não fez nada disso e quer evitar a forma 'descuidada' de solucionar o problema, vamos tentar fazer uma espécie de "engenharia reversa" com `pipreqs` (embora ainda não seja a forma ideal, mas bem próxima disso). Com pipreqs vc constroi seu requirements.txt com base nos seus imports, mas de forma automática e não no olhometro, para isso bastaria fazer:

```
# Instalando o pipreqs
$ pip install pipreqs

# Construindo o requirements.txt
$ pipreqs /path/projeto
INFO: Successfully saved requirements file in /path/projeto/requirements.txt
```

Pireqs criára o requirements.txt no diretório do seu projeto, agora basta inclui-lo no seu instalador e executar o `pip install -r reqirements` na instalação.

Pq eu disse que não é o ideal dessa forma? pq no ambiente de desenvolvimento (mesmo considerando um virtual environment única) voce pode querer instalar alguns pacotes que não sejam necessários no ambiente de produção, então o ideal é sempre trabalhar como virtualenvs, o mais "enxuto possível" e ir adicionando manualmente as libs no requeriments.txt a medida que for desenvolvendo.

Pipreqs tem alguns parametros interessantes, veja:

```
$ pipreqs --help
pipreqs - Generate pip requirements.txt file based on imports

Usage:
    pipreqs [options] <path>

Options:
    --use-local           Use ONLY local package info instead of querying PyPI
    --pypi-server <url>   Use custom PyPi server
    --proxy <url>         Use Proxy, parameter will be passed to requests library. You can also just set the
                          environments parameter in your terminal:
                          $ export HTTP_PROXY="http://10.10.1.10:3128"
                          $ export HTTPS_PROXY="https://10.10.1.10:1080"
    --debug               Print debug information
    --ignore <dirs>...    Ignore extra directories, each separated by a comma
    --encoding <charset>  Use encoding parameter for file open
    --savepath <file>     Save the list of requirements in the given file
    --print               Output the list of requirements in the standard output
    --force               Overwrite existing requirements.txt
```

**Obs.**

Em ambos os casos (da forma correta ou da forma "descuidada") vc não vai mais precisar ficar "carregando" a pasta das bibliotecas na instalação.

Para saber mais sobre o anaconda, [veja essa resposta aqui no STOpt.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/223520/7412)

Comment: Amigo deixa eu te perguntar, estou no windows, e estou tentando executar o pipreqs, tentei deste forma: python C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pipreqs\pipreqs.py e apresenta o seguinte erro: ImportError: cannot import name __version__

Comment: Vc não tem o pip instalado no windows? se não tiver, instale e utilize-o para instalar os pacotes. [Esse link](http://rafs.com.br/como-instalar-pip-no-windows/) pode te ajudar a instalar o pip no windows.

Comment: Eu já instalei o pipreqs utilizando o pip, mas ao tentar executar da este erro.

Comment: Cara... Faz um tempo que não tenho contato com o windows, mas teoricamente teria que ser igual ao linux, bastaria vc dar o comando `pipreqs c:\path\projeto`.  Veja se pipreqs é um binário (executável no windows),  com o comando whereis, se nao me engano no windows é `where`, tente assim `where pipreqs`, se for veja se o caminho dele está na variável path.

Comment: Em tempo: Considere utilizar o anaconda e acabe com seus problemas de pacotes e conflitos deles.

Answer (score 0):

```
=help("modules")
```

Utilize a função nativa `HELP`.
No menu prompt do Python digite: `help("modules")` e o programa retornará a lista de todos os módulos instalados em ordem alfabética.

Observações:

**1)** Na primeira vez pode demorar um pouco;

**2)** A lista é muito completa e mostra módulos internos dos módulos principais e módulos pré-instalados.