# Python3: Module csv has no DictWriter member

Tags: python

Olá. Estou seguindo a leitura do livro Data Visualization with Python and Javascript from Scratch, de Kyran Dale(O'Reilly). No código a seguir, é entendido que deveria-se gravar um arquivo .csv, com o uso da biblioteca csv do Python.

Usando Anaconda2

```
import csv
import os.path

nobel_winners = [
    {'category': 'Physics',
     'name': 'Albert Einstein',
     'nationality': 'Swiss',
     'sex': 'Male',
     'year': 1921},
    {'category': 'Physics',
     'name': 'Paul Dirac',
     'nationality': 'British',
     'sex': 'Male',
     'year': 1933},
    {'category': 'Chemistry',
     'name': 'Marie Curie',
     'nationality': 'Polish',
     'sex': 'Female',
     'year': 1911}
]

mypath = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
path = os.path.join(mypath, './data/nobel_winners.csv')

with open(path,'wb') as f:
    fieldnames = nobel_winners[0].keys()
    fieldnames.sort()
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeHeader()
    for w in nobel_winners:
        writer.writerow(w)
```

No entanto, o que me aparece no pylint é a saída:

> Module 'csv' has no 'DictWriter' member

Como posso solucionar isso?

O livro usa como padrão o Python 2.7, mas mesmo na documentação não achei nada que marcasse esse membro como *deprecated* ou algo assim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz uma pequena mudança no seu codigo e funcionou aqui, veja abaixo as versões que estou utilizando:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.6.7 :: Anaconda, Inc.
~ 
$ python -c "import csv; print(csv.__version__)"
1.0
```

Agora o codigo adaptado, comento as mudanças no proprio codigo:

```
# Ao invés de abrir o aruivo com "wb", abro somente com "w"
with open(path,'w') as f:
    fieldnames = nobel_winners[0].keys()
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()  # ==> Aqui vc usa writeHeader ao invés de writeheader
    for w in nobel_winners:
         writer.writerow(w)
```

Testando a saida do arquivo gerado:

```
$ cat nobel_winners.csv 
category,name,nationality,sex,year
Physics,Albert Einstein,Swiss,Male,1921
Physics,Paul Dirac,British,Male,1933
Chemistry,Marie Curie,Polish,Female,1911
```

Obs.:
Suprimi a linha `fieldnames.sort()` porque as chaves já estão "sorteadas" e, por outro lado, não existe o metodo sort em `dictkeys` mas se vc fizer questão de usar essa linha, use sorted:

```
fieldnames = sorted(fieldnames)
```

Veja a sintaxe do `DictWriter.writeheader()` [aqui](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictWriter.writeheader)

Comment: O seu código está correto, entretanto, ainda mostra a mesma mensagem. Adicional a isso, percebi que na verdade estava executando o Anaconda2 (python 2.7). Para tentar uma última vez, estou baixando o Anaconda3. Obrigado por sua resposta, que aliás, foi bastante precisa (eu ainda estou me acostumando com a sintaxe e ao idioma do python).

Comment: Vc deve estar cometendo algum outro erro (ou é a diferença das versões), aqui esta rodando sem erros. Detalhe: Com o anaconda vc pode ter varias versões do python. Pode inclusive instalar o anaconda 3 e rodar o python 2.7 e todas as versoes dos pacotes que tem no livro que vc esta estudando. Veja [essa resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/223520/7412)

Comment: Na verdade a versão mais nova do anaconda é 4.x.

Comment: De fato, estava com o problema da versão do Python, Agora estou com o Anaconda atualizado, e funcionou. Muito obrigado!